# Which vscode extension can support jsx?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I am looking for a vscode extension that will help me write jsx. For example when I type:

```
div
```

It should go:

```
<div></div>
```

Is there an extension for this or is this a setting in vscode? I am using version 1.17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported natively as of VS Code 1.18. We are tracking the feature request here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34307

Until then, try the [Auto Close Tag extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag). Make sure to add javascript/javascriptreact to the targeted languages:

```
"auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jsx-snippets` plugins for vscode.

Comment: I had this installed already but when I type div ENTER nothing happens?

Comment: Not for me in a js file